# Clustered Standard Errors on POLR ordered logit with vcovCL gives "non-conformable arguments" error

Tags: r, mass

I'm trying to get clustered standard errors on an ordered logit regression using the POLR function from MASS. The regression has about 2,900 fixed effects, (U.S. counties and years.)

When I run the regression without the fixed effects, I'm able to use the vcovCL function from sandwich with no problems, ([using the procedure outlined in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798401/cluster-standard-errors-for-ordered-logit-r-polr-values-deleted-in-estimation)) However, when I include the fixed effects, I get this error:

```
Error in xmat %*% x$coefficients : non-conformable arguments
```

I would post the data, but the data set is quite large and the regression takes about 2 days to run with all the fixed effects.

Has anyone come across a similar problem and have you come up with a solution?

**EDIT:** Following what @ben-bolker commented below, I tried the regression with a random sample of 1,000 lines. It appears that some of the fixed effects produce a square matrix throwing the following errors:

```
   1: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
   2: design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs
```

When I try using the vcovCL function to cluster the standard errors, I get the same "non-conformable arguments" error. So I suspect that since some coefficients are NA's, the matrix vcovCL is a different size from the POLR object and that's what's causing the error.

Is there a way to excise these missing fixed-effects? I won't be displaying them in the regression output anyhow.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem with a smaller data set, i.e. some fixed effects but only a few (and not very many observations)?

Comment: Good idea. I sampled 1000 rows and am finding the same problem. Would it help if I posted the truncated data?

Comment: @ModalBro, did you ever find a solution? I'm currently running into this issue in a very similar context (ordered logit, many fixed effects).