# Cluster-Robust Standard Errors in Stargazer

Tags: r, lm, stargazer, standard-error

Does anyone know how to get `stargazer` to display clustered SEs for `lm` models? (And the corresponding F-test?) If possible, I'd like to follow an approach similar to computing heteroskedasticity-robust SEs with `sandwich` and popping them into `stargazer` as in http://jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer.html#robust-standard-errors-replicating-statas-robust-option.

I'm using `lm` to get my regression models, and I'm clustering by firm (a factor variable that I'm not including in the regression models). I also have a bunch of NA values, which makes me think `multiwayvcov` is going to be the best package (see the bottom of landroni's answer here - [Double clustered standard errors for panel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389843/double-clustered-standard-errors-for-panel-data) - and also https://sites.google.com/site/npgraham1/research/code)? Note that I do not want to use `plm`.

Edit: I think I found a solution using the `multiwayvcov` package...

```
library(lmtest) # load packages
library(multiwayvcov)

data(petersen) # load data
petersen$z <- petersen$y + 0.35  # create new variable

ols1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = petersen) # create models
ols2 <- lm(y ~ x + z, data = petersen)

cl.cov1 <- cluster.vcov(ols1, data$firmid) # cluster-robust SEs for ols1
cl.robust.se.1 <- sqrt(diag(cl.cov1))
cl.wald1 <- waldtest(ols1, vcov = cl.cov1)

cl.cov2 <- cluster.vcov(ols2, data$ticker) # cluster-robust SEs for ols2
cl.robust.se.2 <- sqrt(diag(cl.cov2))
cl.wald2 <- waldtest(ols2, vcov = cl.cov2)

stargazer(ols1, ols2, se=list(cl.robust.se.1, cl.robust.se.2), type = "text") # create table in stargazer
```

Only downside of this approach is you have to manually re-enter the F-stats from the `waldtest()` output for each model.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the packages lmtest and multiwayvcov causes a lot of unnecessary overhead. The easiest way to compute clustered standard errors in R is the modified `summary()` function. This function allows you to add an additional parameter, called cluster, to the conventional `summary()` function. The following post describes how to use this function to compute clustered standard errors in R:

https://economictheoryblog.com/2016/12/13/clustered-standard-errors-in-r/

You can easily the summary function to obtain clustered standard errors and add them to the stargazer output. Based on your example you could simply use the following code:

```
# estimate models
ols1 <- lm(y ~ x) 

# summary with cluster-robust SEs
summary(ols1, cluster="cluster_id") 

# create table in stargazer
stargazer(ols1, se=list(coef(summary(ols1,cluster = c("cluster_id")))[, 2]), type = "text")
```

Comment: I want to create one output with 4 regression models. Each model should have clustered standard errors. How would you set up the code? This is how it looks like for the model without clustered standard errors: stargazer(m1,m2,m3,m4, type="html", dep.var.labels=c("ROA"), intercept.bottom = FALSE, out="OLS1")

Comment: @YaronNolan I'd do the following: clust <- function(m, cluster="cluster_id") {
    return(coef(summary(m, cluster = c(cluster)))[, 2])
}
stargazer(m1, m2, m3, m4, se=list(clust(m1), clust(m2), clust(m3), clust(m4)), ...)

Comment: I used this function, but it gave me the same standard errors as the one without cluster option. Also felm gave another error (very small), and stata gave ne a slightly larger error. No idea why that happens, but might be a good idea to first compare several tools for consistency.

Comment: Note that the code there doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend `lfe` package, which is much more powerful package than `lm` package. You can easily specify the cluster in the regression model:

```
ols1 <- felm(y ~ x + z|0|0|firmid, data = petersen)
summary(ols1)

stargazer(OLS1, type="html")
```

The clustered standard errors will be automatically produced. And `stargazer` will report the clustered-standard error accordingly.

By the way (allow me to do more marketing), for micro-econometric analysis, `felm` is highly recommended. You can specify fixed effects and IV easily using `felm`. The grammar is like:

```
ols1 <- felm(y ~ x + z|FixedEffect1 + FixedEffect2 | IV | Cluster, data = Data)
```

Comment: when I am using the "lm" command my industry and year dummies are displayed. When I m using the "felm" command my industry and yer dummies are not beeing displayed. Does r still take these dummies into account when using your code? This is how my code look like:

Comment: m1_1 <- felm(ROA ~ fam_ownership + lag_investment + dual_class + age + crisis
           |0 | 0 | gvkey,
           data) 

m1_2 <- felm(ROA ~ fam_ownership + fam_ownership_squared + lag_investment + dual_class + age+crisis 
             |0 | 0 | gvkey,
           data)

m1_3 <- felm(ROA ~ fam_ownership + fam_ownership_squared + lag_investment + dual_class + age +crisis
           |as.factor(industry)+as.factor(year)|0| gvkey,
           data)

stargazer(m1_1,m1_2,m1_3, type="html", dep.var.labels=c("ROA"), intercept.bottom = FALSE,
          out="OLS1")

Comment: I just love the fact that the `felm` model output works with `stargazer`, which saved me much time. I also checked that the estimated robust std. errors are the same as STATA output.