# How to create an linear model output with clustered (by firms) standard error in R

Tags: r, cluster-computing, linear-regression, standard-error

[https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArUNQ8J4vgGqhe8IAVP0ulapoEv4uQ?e=wRMEWN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mADMv.png)

I have provided my data frame above and my R code below.

I am trying to cluster standard errors on firm level.

firm id = `gvkey`

I have tried the `miceadds package` but I was not capable of executing it properly.

In the end I want to create an linear regression output including clusterd standard errors on firm level.

the output should look similar to this one:

[image: OUTPUT]

Thank you so much!!!

**Update**

```
m1_1 <- lm_robust(ROA ~ fam_ownership + lag_investment + dual_class + age + crisis, clusters = gvkey
           , 
           data) 

m1_2 <- lm_robust(ROA ~ fam_ownership + fam_ownership_squared + lag_investment + dual_class + age+crisis, 
                  clusters = gvkey,
           data)

m1_3 <- lm_robust(ROA ~ fam_ownership + fam_ownership_squared + lag_investment + dual_class + age +crisis
           + as.factor(industry) + +as.factor(year), clusters = gvkey,
           data)

m1_4 <- lm_robust(ROA ~ fam_ownership + famfirm50 + lag_investment + dual_class + age+crisis
           + as.factor(industry)+as.factor(year), clusters = gvkey,
           data) 


stargazer(m1_1,m1_2,m1_3,m1_4, type="html", dep.var.labels=c("ROA"), intercept.bottom = FALSE,
          out="OLS1")
```

When I am using `lm_robust` and `stargazer` I receive the following error:

```
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

Comment: The link fail because of my company policy, could you upload a smaller sample in the form of a dput result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to calculate clustered standard errors. The easiest is probably to use the [estimatr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/estimatr/index.html) package: instead of using `lm()`, use the `lm_robust()` function with the `clusters` argument.

But `lm_robust()` produces objects of class `lm_robust`, and stargazer won't work with objects of that class. To get clustered SEs in stargazer, see [Cluster-Robust Standard Errors in Stargazer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027482/cluster-robust-standard-errors-in-stargazer).

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my initial post. Do you have any idea why I cannot create an output with stargazer when using lm_robust?

Comment: @YaronNolan - yes, see my edited post for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks! Flavian Barton posted a good answer in the link you have posted. But which code should I use if I want to create one output with 4 regression models. Each model should have clustered standard errors. How would you set up the code? This is how it looks like for the model without clustered standard errors: stargazer(m1,m2,m3,m4, type="html", dep.var.labels=c("ROA"), intercept.bottom = FALSE, out="OLS1")

Comment: @YaronNolan, I'm afraid that I can't help you on that point - I don't use stargazer. You might try to leave a question in a comment on that other post, or to post a new question.